# How to undo an svn update?

Tags: svn

I had modified files in my working directory and did an svn update. The update was performed without conflicts.

I would like to be able to revert the working directory content to the state it was just before the svn update.

The reason is because I maintain a local git repository in parallel to the shared svn repository. I forgot to git commit my local changes before doing the svn update. Now my working directory contains local changes mixed up with changes resulting from the svn update. If I commit, all changes will appear as one atomic change. I wished they would be separate. If I could revert the update and preserve the content of the working directory I had before the svn update, I could do that.

Comment: I solved it in another way. The local changes were in files not affected by the update. So thanks to the git stage mechanism, I only commit the files modified locally, then in a second commit modified all the other files modified by the svn update. I was lucky.

Comment: Yes, the git stage is the way out. Even if the files _were_ affected, you could still use `svn diff` and `git apply` to take apart subversion changes and your changes.

Comment: In either case I'd recommend using `git-svn` in future. It can handle the importing and exporting revisions reliably and additionally can be used as local patch queue (you can have multiple commits on the local branch and push only some of them to subversion using interactive rebase).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. The state before update is forgotten.

You can separate the changes by making subversion diff, using `git apply` to apply it to index, commit that (your changes) and than commit everything (the changes from pull).

That is emergency solution. I suggest you switch to `git-svn`, that will handle this kind of things for you in future.

Comment: IMHO, this is an incredible flaw! VCS's should make it very difficult for you to to do permanent damage to your repository.

Comment: @JanM., yes, it is! Alas as far as I can tell git is the only one that gives you some protection through the reflog and refusing to do non-trivial merges with uncommitted changes. Most other systems will happily clobber modified files with merge results with no backup during update.

Comment: @JanM., to be fair, it is not really damage to the *repository* though, just messing up the work in progress.

Answer (score 17):

I keep hitting this question, and it doesn't actually include the simple answer to the "How to undo an svn update?" question.

So for the benefit of others, with the solvable case where you just wish to roll back an update:

First check the log with:

```
svn log | less
```

This will give you the revision number (eg `957`) that you wish to go back to. Then:

```
svn up -r 957
```

Comment: This answer ignores the case of a modified working directory.

Comment: true @RobertPollak but it answers the question posed by the title of the question...

Comment: Downvoting, because this does not answer the original question (the very first sentence of which contains the note about modified files). This would be an answer to another question "How to update to a specific revision". This answer won't work if there are modified files, and there is no even mention about it.

Answer (score 2):

perform an "Update to Version", so you change your local file to stable version and then re-commit. In this way you lose all local changes.

Comment: Loosing all my local changes is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Obviously in your case, if local changed file are not in conflict, this operation is unuseful. So, you're lucky! ;) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

This is for linux users.

Suppose Revisions as follows.

Head - 20
Previous revisions to head - 18, 17, 15, 14, 10, 9,8.

go to your src directory. 
Use 
svn merge -r 17:18 $url

$url for your svn base.

Answer (score -2):

In case, if there were any conflicts occurred during update, there will be a copy of your file and revision file available in your recycle bin