# Restore deleted directory after SVN Update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I had some uncommited changes on my working copy and left them laying around for a long time. The other guys from my team removed the entire directory where the scripts I was working were. After the update, since they have removed these files on the repo, they have been removed from my working copy too. Reverting the working copy will cause it to revert to the previous update before the latest one, which will unfortunately lose my changes. Any chance to recover my local uncommited changes that have been replaced by the update?

Comment: I'll be honest, this question is hard to follow with the run-on sentences. But to respond to the question as to whether or not you can recover your local uncommitted changes: **More than likely, not**. Your best bet would be to check your Recycle Bin. Fortunately when you do cleans with subversion, the Recycle Bin is where files will go once they are cleaned from a Working Copy (assuming they are small enough). Check there first.

Comment: Nothing on Recycle Bin. I'm using Recuva to see if I can find them.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1342845

Answer (score 0):

This question is to some extent a duplicate of [How to undo an svn update?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19248318/5749914).

As the answer to that question discusses, the answer is that your dirty working copy is gone, gone, gone after you update. SVN cannot help you here.

Of course, if you have *another* backup system (e.g. recycle bin), you can try your luck with that (as discussed in comments).

Next time, consider running `svn status --show-updates` first to see what will happen when you update.